# How to map multiple list to a single list?

Tags: automapper

I have few classes and they have multiple list items like below:

```cs
public class Request1
{
   public List<AdditionalApplicantData> AdditionalApplicantData { get; set;}

   public List<ApplicantData> ApplicantData { get; set; }
}

public class Request2 
{
  public List<ApplicantDetails> ApplicantData { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map `Request1` to `Request2` but List of `ApplicantData` has to be mapped from multiple sources like List of `ApplicantData` & List of `AdditionalApplicantData` but not sure how to achieve it can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ApplicantDetailsResolver : IValueResolver<Request1, Request2, List<ApplicantDetails>>
{
     public List<ApplicantDetails> Resolve(Request1 source, Request2 destination,List<ApplicantDetails> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
     {
        destination.ApplicantDetails = context.Mapper.Map<List<ApplicantDetails>>(source.ApplicantData);

        for (int i = 0; i < destination.ApplicantDetails.Count(); i++)
        {
            context.Mapper.Map(source.AdditionalApplicantData.ElementAt(i), destination.ApplicantDetails.ElementAt(i));
        }

        return destination.ApplicantDetails;
     }
}
```

I have written above custom value resolver for mapping list from multiple sources and its working fine but problem, is it can't match properties which are differently named, is there way I can handle this scenario as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function below with `createMap()` function. Source: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions

```
.AfterMap((src, dest) => {
    dest.ApplicantData = /*your logic here*/
    });
```

And you should mark ApplicantData as `don't map` because you have a variable named `ApplicantData` at the source class. You should implement the logic yourself.

EDIT: 
When you are initializing mapper, you create map for each object. So for your case it would be like:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<Request1, Request2>()
    .ForMember(x => x.ApplicantData, opt => opt.Ignore()) //You want to implement your logic so ignore mapping
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => 
        {
            dest.ApplicantData = /*implement your logic here*/
        });
});
```

Comment: Sorry but can you please elaborate on this as I couldn't follow you here?

Comment: I have just posted one answer, any suggestion on making it better so that it can match properties which are named differently?